# How to join a array and MySQL table in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, join

i have an array like

```
array:5 [▼
  188 => array:17 [▼
    "user_id" => "176"
    "product_id" => "188"
    "qty" => "2"
    "date" => "03-05-2020"
    "product_type" => "rear type"
    "custom_color_title" => ""
    "custom_color_price" => ""
    "bolt_title" => ""
    "bolt_price" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_title" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_price" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_title" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_price" => ""
    "tire_pressure_title" => ""
    "tire_pressure_price" => ""
    "product_price" => 1890
    "product_size" => ""
  ]
  176 => array:17 [▼
    "user_id" => ""
    "product_id" => "176"
    "qty" => "2"
    "date" => "03-05-2020"
    "product_type" => "wheel type"
    "custom_color_title" => ""
    "custom_color_price" => ""
    "bolt_title" => ""
    "bolt_price" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_title" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_price" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_title" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_price" => ""
    "tire_pressure_title" => ""
    "tire_pressure_price" => ""
    "product_price" => 1680
    "product_size" => ""
  ]
  224 => array:17 [▶]
]
```

from a session variable this array 
 and mysql table fields are id,name,img etc.. how to join the array.product_id and table.id  ,

my query like `$table=DB::select('SELECT * FROM products');`i am doing in laravel any way to join mysql table and array?

Comment: I really don't understand anything from your question.

Comment: @ÖmerYilmaz i have an array from session variable ,i wand join the array and mysql table ,any way?

Comment: Please edit your question, write array as array (not dump) and mysql query or result, then write what exactly you want. I will help you.

Comment: @ÖmerYilmaz i will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mysql dump which you want to join is missing. But i think i understand you want:

```
foreach($sessionArray as $sessionArrayKey => $sessionArrayVal)
{
    $findInDb = array_search($sessionArrayVal['product_id'], array_column($dbArray, 'id'));

    if ($findInDb)
    {
        $sessionArray[$sessionArrayKey] = array_merge($sessionArray[$sessionArrayKey],$dbArray[$findInDb])
    }

}
```

Comment: not showing ,$dbArray=DB::select('SELECT * FROM products'); like this

Comment: So reverse them. loop with dbArray and search in SessionArray. or convert your session array to collection and merge with mysql collection. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-mergerecursive